# PostgreSQL & Access -- Connecting at start vs. Connect when needed

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 database with an Access 2016 front-end, using an ODBC driver to connect the two. If I wanted to query data, I would start with the following commands:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};Server=localhost;Database=[name];User Id=[UID];Password=[pass];"

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
```

My question is this: Is there any reason why I shouldn't establish this connection the moment the application opens, using that connection whenever I need to run a query, as opposed to opening and closing the connection each time I run a query?

I'm unsure what, if any, overhead is involved in establishing such a connection in Access, and I've been unable to find any information on the topic. Apologies if this is a naive question.

Comment: There is overhead in connecting to the database, but you are connecting to a local instance, so it is probably very minimal. Alternatively, if your connection remains idle for a period of time it could timeout - how long that would be depends on the database configuration.

Comment: @Nicarus It bears mentioning the final version of this project will have the database hosted on a local network, would the overhead likely be similarly small? Thank you for the insight, though

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you, but you could test it. I suspect it depends on how much concurrent network traffic you have occurring at the times it attempts to connect. If you are worried about it, you can establish a connection at the start and whenever you need to execute a query/command, first check that the connection is still active. If not, reconnect.

Comment: Are you talking about linked tables, or ADODB connections? The latter is easier to establish when you need it, but you can use a predeclared self-healing object if you want to cache the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the connection is cached by Access anyway.

Once you touch, or open any linked table, then the connection is now active, and re-used by Access.

In general if the query is against a single table, then there little reason to not just code against the linked table.

Eg:

```
   Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL  As String

   strSQL = "select * from tblInvoices where invoiceNum = 13355"

   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

If you using a pass-though query, then this works well:

```
Sub Test555()

   Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset

   With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
      .SQL = "select * from tblInvoices where invoiceNum = 13355"
      Set rst = .OpenRecordset
   End With

End Sub
```

The reason for above is you thus don’t mess or have to bother with connection strings in your code.

Just ensure that you table re-link code also re-links any pass-through query.

Comment: That vastly simplifies things, thanks for the succinct answer!